# boto3 publish message SNS

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-sns, boto3

I think i am trying to do something really simple but I am doing something wrong in some point or missing something.

Goal: Send a message from python 2.7 using the boto3 (aws sdk library)

I have the application Key, registrationId, etc...and my code is

```
response = client.publish(
                    TargetArn=platform_endpoint['EndpointArn'],
                    Message="Hi there"
                )
```

Then i receive the messageId from aws, and the notification popup in the terminal movil, but always empty, without any text, "Hi there" in this case. I tried to use the aws SNS console and works, the phone receive the notification with text normally.

I also tried to send a JSON, but same result, and if the easiest goal is failing...better fix this to go for JSON :p

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the solution was use json.dumps to convert the JSON to string

```
response = client.publish(
                TargetArn=platform_endpoint['EndpointArn'],
                Message=json.dumps(jsonObj),
                MessageStructure='json'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will help publish email, prerequisites are topic is created in SNS and subscription is confirmed within the topic in AWS**

```
import boto3
import ipaddress
import warnings
    
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

region = 'ap-southeast-1'
sns_client = boto3.client("sns", region_name=region)

topic_arn = '<topic-arn>'
msg = 'test string'
sub = 'test'


def publish_to_sns(msg, sub, topic_arn):
    topic_arn = topic_arn
    response = sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn=topic_arn,
        Message=msg,
        Subject=sub
    )
    print(response)


publish_to_sns(msg, sub, topic_arn)
```