# Athena Queries, Lambda and SNS

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-athena

I have created a set of custom metrics which I analyse using athena query, however I am trying to automate the process and can safely run the query using a Lambda function but I need the result of that query to be sent via to an SNS topic so I do not have to manualy log in to AWS to view the results daily. I am pretty new to this and need some help pls on how to implement this?

THis is the query I am running using a lamdba function, it is triggered by a event (scheduled on eventbridge). What it does is get disk utilization of my instances, "custom_diskutilization" is a table with a column called use%. I would like to run the query to output result of use% > 70 and send that to an SNS topic.
[Lambda Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR24U.jpg)

[Query Result when I run directly on Athena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIgk1.jpg)

Comment: I can't find official docs specifically on using Athena from Lambda, but [here is an AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/schedule-query-athena/) on how to schedule a Lambda to run an Athena query, which contains example Lambda code

Comment: HI, thanks for your response however I have already implemtneted that and my problem right now is getting the result of that query (which outputs to an S3 bucket) to an SNS topic. I honestly do not need the result in an S3 bucket, I want to be notified of the result via email.

Comment: Gotcha. Please update your question with details of exactly what the problem you're having is. At the moment, it reads like you're asking for a general overview of how Lambda-Athena-SNS integration would be done. Please include all relevant details: the code you have that is not working, what you've tried to fix it, etc. :)

Comment: I have responded, I am new to this page and I tried tp paste the code but was getting errors so I uploaded it as a picture.

Comment: That's much better - I'd go further, and re-write your question to focus on exactly what you don't know how to do: take the Athena query result and publish the results to SNS :) I know the auto code-length check is frustrating, but please try if you can to shorten your code to be able to include it directly. It's much easier to work with copy-pastable code than with a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

So you have the logic to get the query result already, the steps you're missing are

1. Convert the query result into whatever format (object(s)) you want to publish
2. Write the converted result(s) to SNS

For the first step, decide whether you want to publish one notification containing all entries with utilization > 70%, or many notifications, each containing one entry with utilization > 70%. Both are valid approaches, it really depends on what will be more useful coming from the SNS topic. If you're not sure what the query result looks like to begin with, I recommend logging it so you can see the structure.

For the second step, you can check out e.g. [boto3 Publish Message in SNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197774/boto3-publish-message-in-sns) and [boto3 publish message sns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667452/boto3-publish-message-sns) (there are several pretty similar such questions).

Also a note: the right place to put your `> 70%` filter is probably *in* your Athena query, since you have a column for `use %`. This will save you having to add logic in your Lambda, as well as cut down on how much data Athena needs to send back to you.